# Make Symfony forms use simple GET names

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am currenly creating a simple search form, using Symfony 4.1's form builder. Rendering works great, but I lack a bit of control on the way the request is formed.

The generated request looks like:

`http://localhost:8000/fr/search?advanced_search%5Bquery%5D=test&advanced_search%5Bcategory%5D=1&advanced_search%5BverifiedOnly%5D=&advanced_search%5Bsave%5D=`

And I want it to look like:

`http://localhost:8000/fr/search?query=test&category=1&verifiedOnly=`

The code I'm using:

```
$this->ff->create(
                AdvancedSearchType::class,
                null,
                ['csrf_protection' => false]
            )->createView()
```

And

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('query', SearchType::class,
            [
                'attr'=> [
                    'placeholder' => 'search.query'
                ]
            ]
        )
        ->add('category', EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'label' => 'search.category',
                'group_by' => function(Category $category, $key, $value) {
     // Code...
                    return $category->getName();
                }
            ]
        )
        ->add('verifiedOnly', CheckboxType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'search.verifiedOnly',
                'required' => false
            ]
        )
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'search.submitButton'
            ]
        );

}
```

The reason behind this is because it generates widgets like this

```
<input .. name="advanced_search[query]" ..>
```

When I want them like this

```
<input .. name="query" ..>
```

Is there any way to change this? Thank you!

Comment: The form element names are pretty much hard coded into Symfony forms.  No really easy way to change.  Just make your own html form using twig and then pull the data directly from the request object.  Another approach is to POST your search data and then redirect with a prettier url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using the shortcut method provided by Symfony's `ControllerTrait`, the name of the generated form will be automatically derived from the form type's block prefix.

You can change the implicit name for all forms based on this type by overriding the `getBlockPrefix()` method in your form type:

`public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return '';
}`

Or you decide to change the name for just one particular form by giving its name explicitly making use of the form factory that is used under the hood by the controller trait's shortcut methods like this:

`$form = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder('', AdvancedSearchType::class, null, [
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ])
    ->getForm();`

But you need to be careful now. If there is more than one form without a name handled during the same request, the component is not able to decide which of these forms has been submitted and will act as if both had been so.